# swift array uiimage animation

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate a `UIImage` and I have an `UIImageView` called MainPic.

This is the code I am using:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var MainPic: UIImageView!> 

        MainPic.animationImages = [
         UIImage(named: "fox01")!,
         UIImage(named: "fox02")!,
         UIImage(named: "fox03")!,
         UIImage(named: "fox04")!,
         UIImage(named: "fox06")!
        ]

     MainPic.animationDuration = 1
     MainPic.startAnimating()
```

I made sure all the images were in the project. I've tried including them using the .jpg extension.

However, I am getting this error:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use `?` instead of `!` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ha two cases:

1. MainPic is nil
2. One of the UIImage(named: "fox01") is nil

You can easily catch which item is nil, by simply printing all items before using. I can help more if you share more code or upload a simple example which reproducing your case.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply i can now see the problem was my images are in the images.xcassets thats why it wasn't working thanks again how would i access them from there

Comment: You are accessing images in the right way, the problem may be because images are not added to the you target, be sure that this checkmark is active for your target, here is the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/odpcm1g2hpzvel5/Untitled.tiff?dl=0